# How do I get this PHP error ,I can't find the error?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP and I got this error while trying to create a signup page.

> Notice: Undefined index: signup in C:\xampp\htdocs\index\PHP\loginsystem\signup.php on line 34

This is the code of the sign..php

```
<?php
require 'header.php';
?>

<main>

<div class="container">

<h1>Sign up</h1>
<?php

if(isset($_GET['error'])){
    if($_GET['error'] == "emptyfields"){
        echo "<p style='color:coral;'>fill in all fields!</p>";

    }
   else if($_GET['error'] == "invaliedemail&username"){
        echo "<p style='color:coral;'>invalied email and username</p>";

    }
    else if($_GET['error'] == "invaliedemail"){
        echo "<p style='color:coral;'>invalied email</p>";

    }
    else if($_GET['error'] == "invaliedid"){
        echo "<p style='color:coral;'>invalied username</p>";

    }
    else if($_GET['error'] == "passwordcheck"){
        echo "<p style='color:coral;'>invalied password</p>";

    }
}
        else if($_GET['signup'] == "success"){                      //error HERE  
            echo "<p style='color:green;'>sign successful</p>";
    
        }

?>
<form action="signup.inc.php" method="POST" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">

<input class="form-control mx-sm-2" type="text" name = "username" placeholder="User Name">
<input class="form-control mx-sm-2" type="text" name = "email" placeholder="Email">
      <input class="form-control mx-sm-2" type="password" name = "pass" placeholder="Password">
      <input class="form-control mx-sm-2" type="password" name = "pass-repeat" placeholder="repeat-Password">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" name = "signup-submit">Sign up</button>
</form>

</div>

</main>

<?php
require 'footer.php';
?>
```

And this is the code signup.inc.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['signup-submit'])){

  require 'db.inc.php';
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['username']);
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
  $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pass']);
  $pass_repeat = $_POST['pass-repeat'];

 if( empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($pass) || empty($pass_repeat) ){

    header("location:signup.php?error=emptyfields&username=".$username."&email=".$email);
      exit();
 }
 else if (!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/',$username)  ){
    header("location:signup.php?error=invaliedemail&username");
    exit();
 }
 else if (!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    header("location:signup.php?error=invaliedemail&username=".$username);
    exit();
 }
 else if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/',$username)){
    header("location:signup.php?error=invaliedid&mail=".$email);
    exit();
 }
 else if ($pass !== $pass_repeat){
    header("location:signup.php?error=passwordcheck&username=".$username."&email=".$email);
    exit();
 }
 else{
     $sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username =?";
     $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
     if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)){
        header("location: signup.php?error=sqlerror");
        exit(); 
     } else {
         mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$username);
         mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
         mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
         $resultcheck = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
         if ($resultcheck >0){
            header("location:signup.php?error=usertaken");
            exit(); 
         } else {
             $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username,email,pass) VALUES (?,?,?)";
             $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
             if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)){
                header("location: signup.php?error=sqlerror");
                exit(); 
             }
             else{
                 $hashpass = password_hash($pass,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"sss",$username,$email,$hashpass);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                header("location: signup.php?signup=success");
                exit(); 
             }


         }
     }
 }
 mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
 mysqli_close($conn);
 
 
}
     else{
    
        header("location: signup.php");
        exit();
     }
```

Everything is running perfectly but the error message pops out in the signup page interface. How do I remove it or is it something wrong with my code?

Comment: You need to stop using `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: what is the reason? @Dharman

Comment: It damages your data and you really do not need it.

Comment: I will search for this ty for info bruh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to read `$_GET['signup']` when it is not set. I think you by the mistake put the condition into wrong block. Here's an edited code (the php part of `sign.php`):

```
if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
    if ($_GET['error'] == "emptyfields") {
        echo "<p style='color:coral;'>fill in all fields!</p>";

    }
    else if ($_GET['error'] == "invaliedemail&username") {
        echo "<p style='color:coral;'>invalied email and username</p>";

    }
    else if ($_GET['error'] == "invaliedemail") {
        echo "<p style='color:coral;'>invalied email</p>";

    }
    else if ($_GET['error'] == "invaliedid") {
        echo "<p style='color:coral;'>invalied username</p>";

    }
    else if ($_GET['error'] == "passwordcheck") {
        echo "<p style='color:coral;'>invalied password</p>";

    }
    else if ($_GET['signup'] == "success") {
        echo "<p style='color:green;'>sign successful</p>";

    }
} //changed the possition of ending ending curly bracket, so the last condition is in the block
```

Answer (score 0):

In your sign.php wrap your if statement inside another if statement like below:

```
    if(isset($_GET['signup'])){
      // then check for signup success
    }
```

Right now you are directly accessing the signup element of $_GET global array but until you have submitted the form it is not set that is why you get the undefined notice.